# How to install edging slabs to concrete pour

Tags: concrete, shed, garden

I plan to pour a concrete slab for a 10x12ft shed. To try and soften the edges, I was planning on getting some [standard paveing edgers](https://www.diy.com/departments/contemporary-double-sided-buff-paving-edging-h-150mm-t-50mm/86195_BQ.prd) as a surround to the conceret pour.

My plan for the concrete pour is to dig a suitable hole the right size and shape, surround the hole with a suitable wooden frame, put in around 5-10mm hardcord/MOT Type 1, wacker plate it down. Then put edgers around the edge; against hardcore on their bases, and the wooden frame and edge of the hold holding them upright. Then another layer of hardcore/MOT type 1, another wacker, then pour the couple of inches of concrete on top of the hardcore.

Is that acceptable way to do it? Should I instead put the edgers in with their own mortar or somthing instead?

Comment: If you are pouring concrete and the edgers are made of concrete, how are you "softening" anything?   Further, unless you are on some really soft soil you are going to some extremes for the slab floor of a shed.   I put up a 10x12  2x4frame in my backyard. leveled it and had concrete poured for my shed. It lasted 22 years  and was still there when I left.

Comment: Softening the visual impact of the shed. Artistic choice. It will still be physically very hard, but visually will blend in that bit nicer. The ground is pretty soft, and, more worryingly for me, it is on top of an old retaining wall.

Comment: If your soil is soft I think you're going to want more than a couple inches of concrete.  How thick aggregate do you plan?

Comment: 100mm aggregate (50mm of which is below the edging), 100mm concrete.